# button edit change data attribute to input

Tags: javascript, php, html, attributes

I want to assign an input to my data- attributes in this link so I can edit the data, and then change it in database. I'm using the attr("data-start", HTML("<input..>")) here, but it doesn't change anything, when I replace the HTML() with a value it works though.

Here is the list element im working on, i want to change all the data attributes to inputs so i can retrive them later in a save button

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function() {
  /*alert($(this).closest('.cd-schedule__event').find('.seance').data("start")); this one here works*/
  $(this).closest('.cd-schedule__event').find('.seance')
    .attr("data-start", "html('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).data("start")+'">')");
  $(this).data("start").html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).attr("data-start") + '"');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="cd-schedule__event">
    <a data-start="<?php echo $heureD;?>" data-end="<?php echo $heureF;?>" data-content="<?php echo $content;?>" data-event="<?php echo $event;?>" href="#0">
      <em class="cd-schedule__name"><?php echo $content;?></em>
      <ul class="list-inline m-0">
        <li class="list-inline-item">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm rounded-0 edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-edit">&#xE254;</i></button>
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item">
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0 delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-trash">&#xE872;</i></button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not valid OR understandable JS `.attr("data-start", "html('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).data("start")+'">')");`

Comment: What is `"html("nested string")"` supposed to do, had it worked? What is expected output?

Comment: i used this html in another js script where I assign an input to a table td on edit button, and it worked just fine, so I thought it would work here too; $(this).parent("td").html('<input type="text" name="'+nom_col+id_ligne+'" value="'+$(this).val()+'">');

Comment: But just pasting in `"html('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).data("start")+'">')"` is wishful thinking. .html is setting the html of an element. Like `$(someselector).html('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).data("start")+'">')` you cannot just wrap it in quotes and hope it works

Comment: Why do you want to set `data-start` to some HTML?

Comment: Can u enlighten me with a solution to assign an input to those attributes ? I'm not sure if there is a way, maybe I could just use a form modal by clicking on the edit button? i appreciate your help.

Comment: i want to be able to edit the values of those data- attributes through inputs, which the user can access by the button.